# Change marker in the legend in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Suppose that you plot a set of data:

```
plt.plot(x,y, marker='.', label='something')
plt.legend()
```

On the display, you will obtain `.  something`, but how do you do to change it to `- something`, so that the marker that appears in the legend is a line a not a dot?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The solution surely depends on the criterion by which you want to transform the marker. Doing this manually is straight forward:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

line, = plt.plot([1,3,2], marker='o', label='something')
plt.legend(handles = [plt.plot([],ls="-", color=line.get_color())[0]],
           labels=[line.get_label()])

plt.show()
```

[image]

Doing the same in an automated way, i.e. each line in the plot gets its corresponding legend handle, which is a line in the same color, but without markers:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.legend_handler import HandlerLine2D

plt.plot([1,3,2], marker='o', label='something')
plt.plot([2,3,3], marker='o', label='something else')

def update_prop(handle, orig):
    handle.update_from(orig)
    handle.set_marker("")

plt.legend(handler_map={plt.Line2D:HandlerLine2D(update_func=update_prop)})

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: What is the equivalent for scatterplots?

Answer (score 0):

To follow up with more info. If you want to make your marker in the legend more visible when using `plt.scatter()`, you can do the following to automate the marker change process.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

handles, labels, plt.gca().get_legend_handles_labels()
updated_handles = []
for handle in handles:
  updated_handles.append(mpatches.Patch(color=handle.get_facecolor(), label=handle.get_label()))
by_label = dict(sorted(dict(zip(all_labels, updated_handles)).items()))
plt.figlegend(by_label.values(), by_label.keys(), ...)
```

If you would like to use a specific axis, change `plt.gca()` with yours. Also, on line 8 I sorted the legend, which is something you can choose not to do.

Comment: Should be:

handles, labels = plt.gca().get_legend_handles_labels()

Answer (score 0):

It works for 3d plots slightly differently:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

ax = plt.gca()
handles, labels =  ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
updated_handles = []

for handle in handles:              
   updated_handles.append(mpatches.Patch(                                  
   color=handle.get_markerfacecolor(),                                 
   label=handle.get_label()))
                     
by_label = dict(sorted(dict(zip(labels,
                updated_handles)).items()))
                            
ax.legend(by_label.values(), by_label.keys())
```