# Change shape of Ellipse handle in legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I'm trying to plot the labels of some contours and an ellipse in a single legend. I'm almost there (code below), but I'd like the shape associated to the ellipse in the legend to be a straight line, instead of a rectangle as it is by default.

How can I change this?

---

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse

# Random data
ndim, nsamples = 2, 1000
samples = np.random.randn(ndim * nsamples).reshape([nsamples, ndim])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x, y = samples.T
H, X, Y = plt.hist2d(x, y, bins=20, cmap=plt.get_cmap('Greys'))[:-1]

# Plot two contours
contour = ax.contour(
    H.T, levels=(5, 10), extent=[x.min(), x.max(), y.min(), y.max()])

# Plot ellipse
ellipse = Ellipse(xy=(0., 0.), width=3., height=2, angle=45, edgecolor='r', fc='None', label='ellipse')
ax.add_patch(ellipse)

# Get ellipse's handle and label
ellip, ellip_lbl = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()

# Plot legend
plt.legend(ellip + list(reversed(contour.collections)), ellip_lbl + ['1s', '2s'])

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the solution based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48391146/change-marker-in-the-legend-in-matplotlib) answer. The main idea here is to use `ls="-",` by plotting an empty list and grabbing its handle. Store the ellipse's patch in `ax1` and use it to get the label.

```
ellipse = Ellipse(xy=(0., 0.), width=3., height=2, angle=45, edgecolor='r', fc='None', label='ellipse')
ax1 = ax.add_patch(ellipse)

# Get ellipse's handle and label
ellip, ellip_lbl = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()

plt.legend(handles = [plt.plot([],ls="-", color='r')[0]] + list(reversed(contour.collections)),
           labels=[ax1.get_label()] + ['1s', '2s'])
```

[image]

Comment: Hacky, but does the job. Thank you!